# How to map + filter in single loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have asked this question on SO before but I cannot find the question/answers!

Basically I want to create this:

```
Array.prototype.filterAndMap = function(){};
```

where I can use it like so:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].filterAndMap(function(){
     if(i % 2 === 0){
        return i*2;
     }
});
```

the above would return:

```
  [4,8]
```

I think the best way to implement this is using Array.prototype.reduce...but I am not sure.

What I am trying to avoid, is iterating through the list twice:

```
   [1,2,3,4,5].filter(function(){
         return i % 2 === 0;
    })
    .map(function(i){
         return i * 2;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the array and concat the value if valid or an empty array if not.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    result = array.reduce(function(r, a) {
        return r.concat(a % 2 ? [] : 2 * a);
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a % 2 ? [] : 2 * a), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely impossible to combine these two methods (`.map` and `.filter`) since `.filter` doesn't do any logic on elements and `.map` always return **every** element from given array. Hovewer you could try `.reduce` approach, to return only that element, which fulfills given condition.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

const r = arr.reduce((s, a) => (a % 2 ? null : s.push(a * 2), s), []);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` would certainly do the trick:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce((arr, cur) => { 
   if(cur % 2 == 0){
      arr.push(cur * 2); 
   }
   return arr;
}, []);   // => [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, reduce is probably the way to go:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function mapAndFilter(array, filterFunc, mapFunc) {
    return array.reduce((p, c) => {
        if (filterFunc(c)) p.push(mapFunc(c));
        return p;
    }, []);
}

const mapFilteredArray = mapAndFilter(myArray, x => x % 2 === 0, x => x*2);
console.log(mapFilteredArray);
```

Adapt that function to go on the array prototype as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered in specific ways, according to your sample code.

If what you are trying to accomplish is a generic function to `filter` and `map` (although it is not a `map`, it is a `reduce`), this is what you are looking for:

```
var filterAndReduce = function(arr, filterFn, fn) {
  return arr.reduce(function(r, a) {
        return r.concat(filterFn(a) ? [] : fn(a));
  }, []);
};
```

You would use it this way:

```
filterAndReduce([1,2,3,4,5], function(i) {
     return i % 2;
},
function(i) {
    return i * 2
});
```